# Swaping the elements of a list

Tags: java

i am having a List of objects and i i wants to do some operation on the list in such a way that the a particular object should be shifted  to list position 0 and the the object at position 0 will take place the shifted object. the diagram is as shown below.

[image]

the list is as follows

```
final List<Object> list= new ArrayList<Object>();
```

presently i have made two temporary lists as

```
final List<Object> temp1= new ArrayList<Object>();
    final List<Object> temp2= new ArrayList<Object>();
```

to do the operation i am running a loop and on particular condition adding object to temp1  else adding to temp2 , something like as follows :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                if (i==3) {

                    temp1.add(i);

                } else {
                    temp2.add(i);
                }
            }
```

and finally doing

```
list.addAll(temp1);
            list.addAll(temp2);
```

how to do the same logic in redundant and effective steps rather than using temp lists.

Comment: You make an entire copy of the array before?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this [swap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap(java.util.List,%20int,%20int)) method:

```
Collections.swap(List<?> list, int i, int j);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this code:

```
Object temp = list.get(0);
list.set(0, list.get(3));
list.set(3, temp);
```

Comment: If you look at the swap method in the Collections class, it does just the same thing. The temp Object is not necessary, you can express it as a one-liner: `list.set(0, list.set(3, list.get(0)));`. The set method returns the old value, that helps to do the swap...