# How to swap two items in Android ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview in which i have 5 integer items.How to change the positions of items in the listview.Suppose i want to swap first and third items in the listview.How can this be achieved ?Somebody  please help...

Comment: Change the value in your adapter, and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swaping the elements of a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836533/swaping-the-elements-of-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

1.Perform the swap in the List that constitutes your ListView,

```
int temp = list.get(2);
list.set(2,list.get(0));
list.set(0,temp);
```

2.Notify your adapter about this change;

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```